# Replace More Than 1 Instance with PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

Say I have

sometext-somemore--test---test2

how could I have it replace all instaces where there are more than 1 - and have it replace them with just 1 so it would look like this

sometext-somemore-test-test2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $mystr);
```

Answer (score 2):

use a regex: `s/-+/-/` The + says 'one or more of the preceding character'.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a regular expression and the [**`preg_replace`**](http://fr.php.net/preg_replace) function :

```
$str = 'sometext-somemore--test---test2';
echo preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $str);
```

would give you :

```
sometext-somemore-test-test2
```

The pattern I used here : **`-+`**

- Matches a **`-`**
- One or more than one time : **`+`**

  - See [Repetition](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) in the PCRE manual, about this.

And don't hesitate to read the [**PCRE Patterns**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) section of the manual, if you are interested by regular expressions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>for($i=0; $i < strlen($text) - 1; $i++){
        if($text[$i] == $text[$i+1]){
            $text = str_replace($i.$i, $i, $text);
        }
    }</strike>

Nowhere near as efficient as using str_replace() by itself for each character you think might be duplicated, but it will work..

If all you want is to replace two dashes with one:

```
$text = str_replace("--", "-", $text);
```

Comment: I don't see how the for/if loop would work.. as far as I can see, it replaces '55' with '5' if characters 4 and 5 are both 'x'. You'd want to check that $text[$i] == '-' also, and you'd have to use substr_replace($text, '-', $i, 2) instead of str_replace(). Regex is probably the way to go, though.

Comment: @MSpreij: It seems Brendan was trying to create an algorithm to replace arbitrary repeating characters. @Brendan Long: Try this instead: preg_replace('{(.)\1+}', '$1', $text);

Comment: Yeah when i read it, I thought the question was asking how to replace any two repeating characters :\

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
echo preg_replace("/-+/","-","sometext-somemore--test---test2");
//prints sometext-somemore-test-test2
```